# Can you send 1 web service the same parameter but different names?

Tags: c#, web-services

We're creating a web service to receive a value (string). Based on the string, we determine if it's "type 1" or "type 2", and what needs to be done in terms of processing.
So my web service is set up to receive data using:
http://www.mysite.com/service.asmx?op=ProcessData?DataID=string

The client sending the string wants to send it using 2 different requests:
http://www.mysite.com/service.asmx?op=ProcessData?DataIDType1=string
http://www.mysite.com/service.asmx?op=ProcessData?DataIDType2=string

Is this possible for me to know though which type he's sending? I can't set up different signatures for this right? Because they're both the same parameter?

Comment: Presumably you know how to check for what parameters have been passed - so you can look for both the name and the value, and write appropriate code. What did you try so far?

Comment: Have you considered using a second parameter to indicate which type is passed over? Or even better, creating two methods if they actually do two seperate things & expect two seperate inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's akin to writing:

```
public void DoSomething(String inputA)
{
    ...
}

public void DoSomething(String inputB)
{
    ...
}
```

It won't work (and for good reason!) - the method signature is the same.

Imagine the call:

```
MyClass.DoSomething("TEST");
```

Which would it call? Which *should* it call?

Your options (as I see them):

```
public void DoThingA(String input)
{
    ...
}

public void DoThingB(String input)
{
    ...
}
```

Which will give you different method signatures AND represent the fact that you're doing two distinct operation s(which is subsequently cleaner, IMO).

If you insist on a single method signature, you could do:

```
public void DoSomething(String input, object operationType) //where object is whatever type you see fit...
{
    if(operationType == ...)
    {
        DoThingA(input);
    }
    else
    {
        DoThingB(input);
    } 
}
```

Or...

```
public void DoSomething(String input)
{
    switch(input)
    {
        case "A":
            ...
            break;
        case "B":
            ...
            break;
        default:
            ...
            break;
    }
}
```

The most suitable depends on your available options. But I'd create two methods.

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking, but their response seemed so certain and sure that I started second guessing myself, as I'm not up to par on the web services side. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

A method should have a single responsibility, therefore I would recommend two methods.

```
public void FirstMethod(string param)
{
// Do something.
}

public void SecondMethod(string param)
{
// Do something.
}
```

This represents good design and the headache of maintainability later down the line when the client wants to add more functionality will be undoubtedly easier for you!